# Retrieving frames per second - Android / MediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: android, video, bitmap, metadata, media

I'm looking to retrieve 10 frames per sec on a 5 second video using the MediaMetadataRetriever and store them into an Arraylist. I'm not interested in using ffmpeg.

Currently my application is creating 50 still images - 10 identical frames AT every second interval instead of 10 different frames PER second.

```
public class FrameCollector {

MediaMetadataRetriever mmr;

double fps;
double duration;
long counter = 0;
long incrementer;

public FrameCollector(String path, Context context) 
{
    try
    {
    mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(path);

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String fpsString = pref.getString("prefFPS", "10");
    fps = Double.parseDouble(fpsString);
    incrementer = (long) (1000000 / fps);

    String stringDuration = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    duration = Double.parseDouble(stringDuration) * 1000;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ArrayList<Bitmap> getBitmaps() 
{
    try 
    {
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitFrames = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

        Bitmap b = mmr.getFrameAtTime(counter);

        while (counter < duration && b != null) 
        {
            bitFrames.add(b);
            counter += incrementer;
            b = mmr.getFrameAtTime(counter);
        }
        return bitFrames;   
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `getFrameAtTime(counter)` is a wrapper for `getFrameAtTime(counter, OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC)`, meaning that it will read keyframes only. Try using `getFrameAtTime(counter, OPTION_CLOSEST)` instead.

Comment: Actually i'd tried your above code to get all frames from video file but i get only the first frames repeatedly.my duration of video is 127040(2:07sec) divided the video to 32 frames can view all 32 images but all were same images i'd tried a lot to fix it with getFrameAtTime(potions) but no use at all exactly i don't knoe where it goes wrong so can you help me by your full source code should i include any thing in AndroidManifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments from @Michael

"getFrameAtTime(counter) is a wrapper for getFrameAtTime(counter, OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC), meaning that it will read keyframes only. Try using getFrameAtTime(counter, OPTION_CLOSEST) instead"